# The remote server returned an error: (403) while accessing a file C#

Tags: c#

I am able to access the file in the browser where I have logged in.

But when I try to read the same file in code behind. It throws the error:
**The remote server returned an error: (403)**

**Sample Code:**

```
string filepath="https://example.com/file.pdf";  
Uri uri = new Uri(filepath); 
DocViewer viewer = new DocViewer();  
viewer.OpenDocument(uri);
```

Do I need to authenticate from the server to access the file or I can pass the read the cookies from the request and pass it on.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please re-read he [mre] guidance and post reasonably looking code in the question. Clearly you know that "only the authenticated users of application can access the file" but code shown in the post does not make any attempts at sending authentication. Alternatively explain why you believe the request from the app is authenticated (ideally with some capture of app's traffic - you can use tools like Fiddler to capture the requests). Please [edit] post with these details.

Comment: The request is coming from the same application where the files are residing. So, I thought there no need to authenticate again in the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already said that only authed users can access the file, then why do you expect to be able to access in your code without auth?

If you look up that [HTTP status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403), it shows you quite clearly that this is the error.

You need to add auth to your code in order to access the document. Search around, there are no end of examples of how to do this available.